# Fix a brick router with Arduino (usb-to-serial adapter)

Tags: usb, putty, serial

I need to test if my USB to serial adapter is working correctly. I've read somewhere about shorcircuiting RX and DX pins so that to get responde is putty. Problem is i'm not used with putty, so what should happen when I type anything in putty and hit enter, should it repeat the same input in the screen? I would have 2 of the same writings side-by-side, is that it?

Comment: Why don't you just hook up the arduino to the serial adapter and follow the normal directions for the task your trying to do?

Comment: because I've got no output from it, so I'm trying to test the arduino itself I've bought from china

Comment: Ok it seems that If I'm seeing caracteres in the putty screen than it's because it's getting data from RXD... otherwise I can type and nothing appears in putty terminal. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, shorting the RX/TX pins works. This called a loopback. You should configure putty to open your serial port (i.e. COM1) and then type something, you should see on screen what you typed.

Comment: Ok, it worked. Now to the defective router, when I connect it to arduino and to putty putty shows nothing comming from it. What other test could I do to check what's wrong?

Comment: You should accept this answer, then ask a new question.

Comment: it's the same theme, and actually is what I'm really worried about, fixing the brick.